# Непрерывный ввод Python

Tags: python, ввод

Как сделать ввод непрерывным? То есть, например, в первой конструкции `try` - `except` выпадет ошибка, и тогда программа должна будет предложить пользователю начать ввод заново, и так во всех "слабых местах", где может случится прерывание.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

while True:

    try:
        m = int(input("Введите число от 2 до 5 - размер матрицы: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Нужно вводить только целые числа, а не строки или дробные числа!")
        exit()

    if m < 2 or m > 5:
        print("Вы ввели неверное значение, размер матрицы должен соответсвовать диапазону из задания!")
        exit()

    ask = input("Матрица содержит только целые цисла в диапазоне от 1 до 100.\nХотите заполнить матрицу случайно - "
                "введите 'y', если с клавиатуры введите 'n': ")

    if ask == 'y':
        MatrixRandomCreator(m)

    elif ask == 'n':
        MatrixSelfCreator(m)

    else:
        print("Нужно вводить 'y' или 'n', а не числа или другие буквы!")
```

Comment: exit() в коде для чего?

Comment: В случае если ввели неправильное значение - завершаем выполнение. Пробовал с brake, но с ним тоже не работает

Comment: т.е. вы хотите предложить пользователю начать ввод заново, но вставляете в код команду, которая завершает выполнение?

Comment: Я понимаю, что это неверное место в моем коде. Однако если я убираю exit, то он продолжает выполняться, т.е. от try exception просто нет толку и он выпадает в ошибку на следущем шаге, если,например, ввести q вместо цифры

Comment: А если я использую break, то программа также просто завершается

Answer (score 1):

Замените `exit()` на `continue`..

Comment: Спасибо вам, это то что надо было!